# Remove portion of duplicated SASS code in nesting class

Tags: css, sass

**What i want to achieve with normal CSS:**

```
.reduit__search-input {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important;
}
.reduit__search-input:not(.error--text), .reduit__search-input:not(.error--text) fieldset {
  border-color: var(--v-primary-base);
}
```

**How i've written with SASS:**

```
.reduit__search-input {
  border-width:2px ;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important;
  &:not(.error--text) , &:not(.error--text) fieldset {
    border-color: var(--v-primary-base);
  }
}
```

**My question :**

As you noticed `&:not(.error--text)`  is repeated twice in SASS, I wonder if there is a trick to simplify this ?

Comment: There really isn't a way to "simplify" what you have - you essentially would still need to write something to create the `fieldset` selector chain - you _probably_ would end up writing more code to achieve essentially what you already have - in a less readable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&:not(.error--text)` like parent level and use it in nested selectors (`&, fieldset`) to omit code duplicates:

```scss
.reduit__search-input {
  border-width:2px ;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important;

  &:not(.error--text) {
    &, fieldset {
      border-color: var(--v-primary-base);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```css
.reduit__search-input {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important; }
  .reduit__search-input:not(.error--text), .reduit__search-input:not(.error--text) fieldset {
    border-color: var(--v-primary-base); }
```

---

Another way, you can do next:

You can try to use [SASS Placeholder approach](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors), in case of using placeholder selector to extend, `border-primary-base` will not render in CSS output:

```scss
%border-primary-base {
  border-color: var(--v-primary-base);
}

.reduit__search-input {
  border-width:2px ;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important;

  &:not(.error--text) {
    @extend %border-primary-base;

    fieldset {
      @extend %border-primary-base;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```css
.reduit__search-input:not(.error--text), .reduit__search-input:not(.error--text) fieldset {
  border-color: var(--v-primary-base); }

.reduit__search-input {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0% !important; }
```

Comment: The parent selector is not required before `fieldset` since it's nested, so you can simply write: `&, fieldset`